# Cannot connect asus zenphone to my laptop

Tags: android-studio

I want to test my android app on my asus zenphone4, model Asus_T00Q. I tried to install the OEM driver but it is not work at all. The ADB cannot recognize my device.
I download the driver from asus support.
Does anyone have some tips? Could i download driver from anywhere else? Is the model id correct?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be ADB driver problem
I tried this for ADB driver installation - [grab from here](http://dl.adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip)

It isn't device specific but contains all...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's fixed.

Comment: Pleased to help 